# Is it possible to dynamically toggle the hotkey of my Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome Extension and I have assigned a hotkey to my Chrome Extension (to open the extension popup)

Though some people enjoy the shortcut access, yet a few of people complain that the hotkey is conflicting with some of their other settings.

Is it possible to use my own interface to control the hotkey behavior rather than asking users to go to chrome://extensions/configureCommands to set up? This is annoying because if the user had installed a lot of extensions, it's a long time to locate my extension.

This is how I set up the hotkey:

```
"commands": {
   "_execute_browser_action": {
     "suggested_key": {
       "windows": "Alt+Q",
       "mac": "Alt+Q",
       "chromeos": "Alt+Q",
       "linux": "Alt+Q"
     }
   },
   "_execute_page_action": {
     "suggested_key": {
       "default": "Alt+Q",
       "windows": "Alt+Q",
       "mac": "Alt+Q"
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no.

It's the intended behavior that you provide *one* default suggestion and extensions grab them on first come, first serve basis.

<del>What's unfortunate is that you don't even know if it conflicts or not.</del> To be on the safe side, you can omit the default shortcut altogether and always instruct the users to set it themselves.

You can programmatically open `chrome://extensions/configureCommands` for the user with `chrome.tabs.create`*, but you can't force it to scroll to the intended input.

** Note: this won't work on Firefox WebExtensions, as privileged URLs cannot be opened by extensions. To be fair though, I don't know where it's configured in Firefox..*

**Update:** I believe I was mistaken. You can query the state of the command with [`chrome.commands.getAll()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands#method-getAll), and it's supposed to return the *current* shortcut. So you should be able to detect when the shortcut was not set due to conflict. But you can't do anything about it except directing the user to fix it.

Comment: oh, sadly i was even going to build a context menu for that. now i can save  a lot of time :P